# Codeigniyer 3.0.4 Session class showing strange behavior

Tags: php, session, cookies, codeigniter-3

Since I upgraded my code co CI 3.x, I'm having really bad issues with session handling. Has anyone here experienced those issues and is there any fix for this?

Here are few of them

1. Session gets destroyed on one controller and its still available on another controller after page reloads
2. Session is sometimes not available in most controllers and views
3. Session class is initialized but when I try to destroy a session, it get session is not initialized error.

*So far I've tried*

1. files and database drivers
2. setting cookie names
3. setting cookie domain

*Here are my observations so far*

1. In case of files, session does not delete session files in /var/lib/php5 when we destroy session
2. session cookie is auto-generated on every page refresh even if i delete it

*See these logs*

```
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Config Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> URI Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Router Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Output Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Input Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Language Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Loader Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Helper loaded: url_helper
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Helper loaded: cms_helper
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Helper loaded: global_helper
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Helper loaded: security_helper
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
**ERROR - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Severity: Warning --> ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time /home/casper/Documents/webapps/fca/system/libraries/Session/Session.php 313
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Session: Class initialized using 'files' driver.**
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Controller Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Model Class Initialized
**ERROR - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Severity: Warning --> session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session /home/casper/Documents/webapps/fca/application/controllers/Register.php 536**
INFO - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Final output sent to browser
DEBUG - 2016-06-20 15:17:58 --> Total execution time: 0.0282
```

Comment: how are you loading the session class? have you set a session key in the config file?

Comment: I tried both autoload and loading manually

Comment: did you set a session key in the config file? also just put it in autoload array in the config file